# Making an Arbitrary Instance for a newtype that uses Maybe

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I want to create an `Arbitrary` instance for the following newtype, in order to use it for QuickCheck:

```
newtype Wrapmaybe a = Wrapmaybe {getMaybe :: Maybe a} deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I know that the `Arbitrary` instance for `Maybe` can be written as follows:

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (Maybe a) where
     arbitrary = frequency [(1, return Nothing), (1, liftM Just arbitrary)]
```

How do I write the `Arbitrary` instance for something like the following without getting a type error or kind error:

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (Wrapmaybe Maybe a) where
   etc...
```

Comment: To write such an instance, you must change the definition of `Wrapmaybe` - perhaps you are looking for `newtype Wrap f a = Wrap (f a)`

Answer (score 11):

Well, you could just replace each `Maybe` constructor in that instance with the corresponding constructor for your newtype:

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (WrapMaybe a) where
  arbitrary = frequency [ (1, return $ WrapMaybe Nothing)
                        , (1, fmap (WrapMaybe . Just) arbitrary) ]
```

However, it's simpler to just do this once for the result, using the already existing `Maybe` instance:

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (WrapMaybe a) where
  arbitrary = fmap WrapMaybe arbitrary
```

You can also write `WrapMaybe <$> arbitrary`. But please do *not* use `liftM`, that is [obsolete](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal)! (These are all equivalent.)

Comment: ...or turn on `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` and add `Arbitrary` to to the list of derived instances.

Comment: `liftM` isn't any more obsolete than `ap`. `liftM` is for writing `Functor` instances and `ap` is for writing `Applicative` ones. Other uses, however, are indeed obsolete.

Comment: @dfeuer: except there's no good reason to ever define `fmap = liftM`. Usually, the `Functor` instance can just be derived (unlike `Applicative`), and else it's generally dead simple to define `fmap` yourself – and pretty often that instance will either be more general or more efficient than a monad-derived one. OTOH, `<*> = ap` is quite handy since the difficulty of implementing `<*>` and `>>=` is similar, so you can save considerable work by only worrying about the latter.

Comment: very helpful answer! seeing the multiple possibilities is very informative.  Thanks very much your help :)

Comment: For some monads (especially those based on continuation passing): `ap` is a lot slower than directly implementing `<*>`

Comment: @JeremyList: sure – for serious applications, you generally want to define both `fmap` and `<*>` directly. My point was that, while it makes _sometimes_ sense to define the latter in terms of `ap` (at least during prototyping), it makes virtually never sense to define `fmap` in terms of `liftM`.